# Teaching aid for online mathematics course

Tags: mathematical-pedagogy, online-instruction, online

Crossposting from the math.stackexchange ([Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3781227/a-question-about-online-teaching-aids?noredirect=1#comment7786199_3781227))

Online classes will start again as the semester will start, I bought an XP-Pen deco 03 to help me with online teaching. I will be teaching commutative algebra next semester. I would like to ask what should be the best software (whiteboard software or any other) that goes well with this pen tablet and easy to write mathematics.

I explored google [Jamboard](https://jamboard.google.com) it is good, but minimal for the choices (there is just one pen, etc ). On the plus side, I can invite all my students and teach totally on the board (although the audio is not streamed through it for which I have to fall back on something like google meet, in that case sharing the window is better). Another thing I don't like about it is the lack of full-screen mode.

I would like to ask people here for some suggestions.

Comment: Do you have a learning management system like Blackboard available? E.g., Blackboard has Collaborate built-in for this purpose. More generally, I would recommend using whatever your school officially supports. At least in the U.S. their are legal/privacy considerations that it's nice to have institutional support for.

Comment: We have moodle and Microsoft OneNote. Creating online quizzes in Latex (like google form, or like quizzes in Google classroom, unfortunately, these two, to my knowledge, do not support \LaTeX (MathJax); would like to be proven wrong though.